# On opening a BluRay disc, VLC either won't detect Java or crashes when detecting it

Tags: windows-10, java, vlc-media-player, blu-ray

On Windows 10, I am trying to read BluRays with VLC and MakeMKV installed. I have the latest versions of both (3.0.17.4 64 bits version for VLC, 1.16.7 32 bits version for MakeMKV).

At first I could play the BluRay, but without any disc menu as Java was not installed (VLC directly plays one of the title of the disc, and displays a message that it needs Java to be able to play the disc menus).

I then installed Java 8 32 bits from java.com. I actually followed the whole procedure from this page : https://stolafcarleton.teamdynamix.com/TDClient/1893/StOlaf/KB/ArticleDet?ID=128854 . But still VLC was saying that it couldn't find any Java installed.

Then I removed the 32 bits Java version and installed the 64 bits version instead (still Java 8 ). Now VLC is crashing when opening the BluRay... At least it shows that it detects Java...

Any suggestion ?

Comment: It's unclear why you're installing 32-bit versions in a 64-bit OS and I think those experiments are part of the problem.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Java 32 bits was the default download from java.com (and they recommended it even for Windows 64 bits, in case we use a 32 bits browser). Anyway it doesn't work with the 64 bits version either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found on the VLC forum: there is a problem with the latest Java 8 update (331). Reverting to the previous Java 8 update (321) worked for me, and now VLC displays the BluRay menus.

VLC forum: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=159727
Older Java 8 versions: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html (creating an Oracle account is required)